# How to tell if two cells are equal in Google Apps Script for Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am writing a script to bind two cells to always hold the same value after every edit. My script so far looks like this:

```
function myEdit(event){
  var ss = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var bind1 = ss.getRange("D11:D11").getCell(1,1);
  var bind2 = ss.getRange("D10:D10").getCell(1,1);
  var editedCell = r.getCell(1,1);

  Logger.log("checking");
  if (editedCell === bind1){
    Logger.log("Condition was Met!");
    bind1.copyTo(bind2);
  }
  else if (editedCell === bind2){
    Logger.log("Condition was met!");
    bind2.copyTo(bind1);
  }
  else{
    Logger.log("No condition was met.");
  }
```

When I change the value in either of the bound cells, nothing is copied anywhere else. When I check the execution logs, it appears everything went fine

```
[14-07-21 10:47:06:215 EDT] Execution succeeded [0.884 seconds total runtime]
```

But when I check the Logger logs, I get

```
[14-07-21 10:55:49:260 EDT] checking
[14-07-21 10:55:49:260 EDT] No condition was met.
```

For some reason, the program is not recognizing that editedCell and bind1 are the same object, when I edit cell D11.

By checking the values of bind1 and editedCell, the values are the same so they must be referring to the same cell, but the equality operator is not working to check whether they are the same range.

Comment: All `Execution succeeded` means, is that the code ran without any errors.  It doesn't mean that it did what you wanted it to do.  Put `Logger.log()` statement in for all your variables, or run Debug, step through each line of code, and view the variable values in the debug window.

Comment: Yup! I mentioned the execution succeeded just so people would know there weren't any "failed to execute" errors or the like. Logger.log(editedCell) just prints out the word "Range". If I Logger.log(editedCell.getValue()) it prints out the value of the desired cell. Also, (editedCell.getValue() === bind1.getValue()) evaluates to true, but (editedCell === bind1) evaluates to false.

Comment: Range is the return type of the class Range.  [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#)  I think there is another step.  You then need to use the `getValue()` method on the class Range.  `var editedCell = r.getCell(1,1).getValue()`

Comment: Basic javascript: `(editedCell === bind2)` will only evaluate `true` when `editedCell` and `bind2` are the exact same object. It does not compare the attributes of those objects.

Comment: I do not want to compare the values of the objects. I want them to be the same object. Cell D10 should be cell D10 regardless of if I get it from event.source.getActiveRange() or event.source.getActiveSheet.getRange("D10:D10"). I cannot check whether they are the same based on value because lots of unbound cells might also have the same value, and I do not want to bind based on that logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For some reason, the program is not recognizing that editedCell and bind1 are the same object, when I edit cell D11.

The reason that the *identity* operator `===` doesn't work in this case is that what is being compared is the Range, not the content of the cells in those ranges. Like Sandy suggests, you need to get the values first, and compare those.

However, comparison isn't needed, is it? Your stated objective is to ensure D10 and D11 contain the same value after every edit. Since the only edit that can affect either is a change to themselves, you can ignore any edit made to any cells but D10 or D11. Further, if either of them changes, and `myEdit()` is invoked, you *know* they are different, so you can just copy the newly changed value to the other cell.

Something like this:

```
function myEdit(event){
  // To check whether we need to do anything, find which cell was edited.
  // Get the A1 notation for the changed cell.
  var cellA1 = event.range.getA1Notation();

  if (cellA1 == "D10") {
    // D10 changed, so copy value to D11
    event.range.offset(1,0).setValue(event.value);
  }
  else if (CellA1 == "D11") {
    // D11 changed, so copy value to D10
    event.range.offset(-1,0).setValue(event.value);
  }
  // Any other cell, do nothing.
}
```